# Json connection to Angular Js .success() is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
$http.get('data/stock.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.stock = data;
})
```

and i also tried this

```
$http.get('data/stock.json').then(function(data){
    $scope.stock = data;
})
```

my Data is in stock.json file no problem in HTML which is working and i m working on angular 1.6 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 1.6, The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. So you have to use the standard then method instead. So change your code like this:

```
$http.get('data/stock.json').then(function(data){
    $scope.stock = data.data;
})
```

Comment: Its mentioned in the documentation of $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http